# Sort a list by length of words and put into dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a list of words like

```
["abc","hello","i"]
```

and I want to store these in a dictionary where the key is the length of the word.

I have only gotten as far as initializing the dictionary.

Comment: Do you actually need to sort the list before putting it into the dictionary?

Comment: Do you want a dictionary with integers as keys and list of words as values?

Comment: @Scooter I don't want to sort them, in the end I just want to be able to print all the one letter words/two letter words etc.

Comment: @Tichordroma Yes...if I have interpreted that right. I want key: value is word length : word for example {1: ["i"], 2,......}

Comment: wouldn't you run into having duplicate key if your list grows?

Answer (score 3):

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function, and a dict expression to build the result. The pythonic way

```
>>> from itertools import groupby    
>>> data=["abc","a", "bca", "hello","i"] #more than one result by word-length
>>> keyfunc = lambda x:len(x)
>>> data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
>>> {k:list(g) for k, g in groupby(data,keyfunc)}
{1: ['a', 'i'], 3: ['abc', 'bca'], 5: ['hello']}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the old days before `defaultdict`, we use to write where `l` is the list of words:

```
d = {}
for w in l:
  if len(w) in d:
      d[len(w)].append(w)
  else:
      d[len(w)] = [w]
```

Which results in `d` being `{1: ['i'], 3: ['abc'], 5: ['hello']}`.

With `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for w in l:
    d[len(w)].append(w)
```

Which results in `d` being `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['i'], 3: ['abc'], 5: ['hello']})`. And can be easily turned into a `dict` via `dict(d)`, resulting in `{1: ['i'], 3: ['abc'], 5: ['hello']}`.

Comment: Ah this is exactly what I wanted to do, where I was going wrong was the append.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to

```
array = ["abc","hello","i"]
dict = {}
for i in array:
    dict[len(i)] = i
```

The main problem is that in a dictionary can be put only one value per key, so if you have more than one word that have the same length, only the last world you put in will be saved.

Comment: "so if you have more than one word that have the same length, only the last world you put in will be saved" If you know this, why post this "answer"?

Answer (score 0):

```
words = {}
words[3] = "abc"
words[5] = "hello"
words[1] = "i"
```

Comment: If I look at the comments this seems to be what you want. Please others comment if I am wrong

Comment: I think (hope) he wants a solution that works for every list of string. You could have writter directly `{1: "i", 3: "abc", 5: "hello"` as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, it can be done with the following code:

```
d = {}
l = ["abc","hello","i"]
for item in l:
    d.setdefault(len(item), []).append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code:

```
dict = {}
elements = ["varun","rahul","rishabh"]
for item in elements:
    dict.setdefault(len(item), []).append(item)
```

Comment: A little explanation would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using a comprehension:

```
mydict = {len(i): i for i in list_of_words}
```

Edit: for updated OP needs this is not useful - it only records one word per word length key. I can't figure out how to do the equivalent of perl's

```
push @list, value
```

with autovivification.

Comment: You would need to create the list_of_words array: list_of_words=["one","hello","i"]

Comment: I had done. The problem was that I was using python 2.6 not 2.7 (or 3.x)